# ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#

I have just started with Visual Studio C# Express. I am building a small database app have encountered the following problem. I get a `System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException`.

Here is the MainWindow.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfApplication1.EnergyDataSet energyDataSet = ((WpfApplication1.EnergyDataSet)(this.FindResource("energyDataSet")));

            // Load data into the table energy. You can modify this code as needed.
            WpfApplication1.EnergyDataSetTableAdapters.energyTableAdapter energyDataSetenergyTableAdapter = new WpfApplication1.EnergyDataSetTableAdapters.energyTableAdapter();
            energyDataSetenergyTableAdapter.Fill(energyDataSet.energy);
            // add a ColumnChanged event handler for the table.
            energyDataSet.energy.ColumnChanged += new
                DataColumnChangeEventHandler(Column_Changed);

            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource energyViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("energyViewSource")));
            energyViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();

        }

        private static void Column_Changed(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfApplication1.EnergyDataSet energyDataSet = ((WpfApplication1.EnergyDataSet)(Application.Current.FindResource("EnergyDataSet")));

            if (e.Column.ColumnName == "Gas Reading")
            {

                DataRowCollection rowCollection =  energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows;
                DataRow foundRow = energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows.Find(e.Row["DateTime"]);
                int frIndex = rowCollection.IndexOf(foundRow);
                energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows[frIndex]["Gas_Diff"] =
                     (float)energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows[frIndex]["Gas_Reading"] -
                     (float)energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows[frIndex - 1]["Gas_Reading"];
                energyDataSet.AcceptChanges();

            }
            if (e.Column.ColumnName == "Elec Reading")
            {
                DataRow foundRow = energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows.Find(e.Row["DateTime"]);
                int frIndex = energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows.IndexOf(foundRow);
                energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows[frIndex]["Elec_Diff"] =
                     (float)energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows[frIndex]["Elec_Reading"] -
                     (float)energyDataSet.Tables["energy"].Rows[frIndex - 1]["Elec_Reading"];
                energyDataSet.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs with the first instance in Coloumn_Changed of the following line:

```
WpfApplication1.EnergyDataSet energyDataSet = ((WpfApplication1.EnergyDataSet)(Application.Current.FindResource("EnergyDataSet")));
```

The call in Window_Loaded using 'this' works ok.

Comment: @DJKRAZE, you don't need a database to use a DataSet...

Comment: Thomas I am baffled by your comment.   I come from a C, Delphi, Java background and am trying to get to grips with C# which I am finding rather alien at  the moment.   Since this is a trivial program I regard errors as part of the learning process and would like to explore their implications as far as possible.  Could you kindly add to your comment.

Comment: don't mind my comment, I was just replying to DJ KRAZE's comment, but he removed since then... It was not directed to you and was not directly related to your question.

Comment: Resolved this problem by removing static from the Column_Changed definition.

Answer (score 3):

```
(this.FindResource("energyDataSet")));
(Application.Current.FindResource("EnergyDataSet")));
```

Note that resource names are case sensitive! energyDataSet vs EnergyDataSet.

Comment: Thanks - the strange thing is that the call that works has a lower case e although the actual resource is shown in the Solution Explorer with a cap E which made me think that it isn't case sensitive.   The following line is in EnergyDataSet.Designer.cs :- [global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("EnergyDataSet")]